Symbol not found/accessible from another gradle subproject, modular java
I am building a couple modular java projects, and have them setup as gradle subprojects. They're both modular java, and I want one(linrboot) to reference a class in the other(linr), but VSCode is saying it's not accessible while the build fails cause it can't find the symbol. I'm sure there's just something basic I'm missing.
File structure
.
| settings.gradle
| gradlew
| linrboot
| | build.gradle
| | bin
| | build
| | src
| linr
| | build.gradle
| | bin
| | build
| | src

settings.gradle
plugins {
    // Apply the foojay-resolver plugin to allow automatic download of JDKs
    id 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention' version '0.8.0'
}

rootProject.name = 'linr'
include'linr', 'linrboot'


linrboot build.gradle
import org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.9'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '3.0.1'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = '22.0.1'
    configuration = 'implementation'
    modules = ['javafx.base', 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.media', 'javafx.swing']
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.10'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.12.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.16.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:2.1.3'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail:2.0.3'
    implementation 'org.update4j:update4j:1.5.9'
    implementation project(':linr')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

test {
    useJUnit()
}

application {
    mainModule = "com.dittmer.linrboot"
    mainClass = "com.dittmer.linrboot.App"
}

linrboot module-info.java
module com.dittmer.linrboot 
{
    requires java.base;

    requires javafx.swing;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires transitive javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires org.update4j;

    requires com.dittmer.linr;

    exports com.dittmer.linrboot;
    
}


linr build.gradle
import org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.9'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '3.0.1'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = '22.0.1'
    configuration = 'implementation'
    modules = ['javafx.base', 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.media', 'javafx.swing']
}

dependencies {
    
    implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.10'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.12.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.16.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:2.1.3'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.angus:angus-mail:2.0.3'
    implementation 'org.update4j:update4j:1.5.9'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}


def currentOS = DefaultNativePlatform.currentOperatingSystem
version = "1.0"

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'Linr'
    }
    forceMerge('log4j-api')
    if (currentOS.isWindows()) {
        jpackage {
            installerType = 'msi'
            icon = "${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources/com/dittmer/linr/icons/linr.ico"
            installerOptions = [
                    '--win-menu',
                    '--win-menu-group', 'DittmerLabs',
                    '--win-shortcut-prompt',
                    '--win-upgrade-uuid', '52910e5b-eb4c-4d58-b892-a2679656861c',
                    '--win-dir-chooser',
                    '--copyright', 'Copyright (c) 2024 DittmerLab',
                    '--description', 'Linr is a new way of taking line notes for theatrical productions.',
                    '--vendor', 'DittmerLabs',
                    '--license-file', 'LICENSE.md',
                    '--app-version', "${project.version.toString()}",
                    '--about-url', 'https://github.com/DittmerK',
            ]
        }
    } else if (currentOS.isLinux()) {
        jpackage {
            installerType = 'rpm'
            icon = "${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources/com/dittmer/linr/icons/Linr.png"
            installerOptions = [
                    '--linux-shortcut',
                    '--linux-package-name', 'com.dittmer.linr',
                    '--linux-rpm-license-type', 'AGPL',
                    '--copyright', 'Copyright (c) 2024 DittmerLabs',
                    '--description', 'Linr is a new way of taking line notes for theatrical productions.',
                    '--vendor', 'DittmerLabs',
                    '--license-file', 'LICENSE.md',
                    '--app-version', "${project.version.toString()}",
                    '--about-url', 'https://github.com/DittmerK/'
            ]
        }
    } else if (currentOS.isMacOsX()) {
        jpackage {
            installerType = 'dmg'
            icon = "${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources/com/dittmer/linr/icons/Linr.png"
            installerOptions = [
                    '--mac-package-name', 'Linr',
                    '--mac-package-identifier', 'com.dittmer.linr',
                    '--mac-app-category', 'public.app-category.music',
                    '--copyright', 'Copyright (c) 2024 DittmerLabs',
                    '--description', 'Linr is a new way of taking line notes for theatrical productions.',
                    '--vendor', 'DittmerLabs',
                    '--license-file', 'LICENSE.md',
                    '--app-version', "${project.version.toString()}",
                    '--about-url', 'https://github.com/DittmerK/'
            ]
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnit()
}

application {
    mainModule = "com.dittmer.linr"
    mainClass = "com.dittmer.linr.App"
}

linr module-info.java
module com.dittmer.linr 
{
    requires java.base;

    requires javafx.swing;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires jakarta.mail;
    requires org.eclipse.angus.mail;
    requires transitive javafx.controls;
    requires transitive com.jfoenix;
    requires transitive org.apache.pdfbox;
    requires org.apache.commons.text;
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
    requires javafx.graphics;

    exports com.dittmer.linr;
}

I expect the symbol to be visible and accessible. I've dug through other forum posts and the gradle docs and everything seems to be right?
